# Cognos querying Impala data source

Tags: impala, cognos

I am not a Cognos expert, but I am trying to get Cognos to query Impala via JDBC correctly.

Setup:

1. Cognos 11.1.7-2106251648 (FP3)
2. Impala (cdh) 3.2.0

I tried various Impala JDBC drivers from cloudera (JDBC4, 41, 42) versions (2.6.17, 2.6.18, 2.6.23)

And I also tried Hive JDBC driver in Cognos to connect to Impala

I have the following issue:

When I run the report, Cognos deploys two queries into impala (I can see it in Impala query logs).
When the first query is done and Cognos fetches the first batch of rows, Cognos stops the connection and runs the query again.

Hive driver - cancels the first query after N seconds (when the first fetch is done), the cancel is successful and then the Cognos runs query second time and fetches all data

Impala driver - cancels the first query after N seconds (when the first fetch is done), the cancel is NOT successful (the query runs in Impala, but Cognos disconnects) and then the query runs a second time and Cognos fetches all data. The issue is that the query still runs in Impala and gets dropped after approx. 5minutes.

I think there is some issue, that Cognos is sending the query twice.

Edit1:
I am using dynamic query mode in Cognos.
I enabled full logging for a few minutes and I found following

The cognos is doing something called
14:01:41 borrowConnection in(JDBC)
14:01:49 borrowConnection out(JDBC)
14:01:49 borrowConnection in(JDBC)
times 14:01:41 and 14:01:49 are the exact times when first and second (same) query were executed in Impala

Comment: you can check what is in your cognos repot log? sometime some reporting system runs lot of SQLs to fetch parameters like sysdate/static values from DB.

Comment: Can you tell me which file is report log? I mostly check p2pd.log file

Comment: i agree, finding report logs arent easy so may be you can check with your cognos admin. You can refer to this link too- https://www.toolbox.com/tech/big-data/question/does-cognos-report-studio-generate-a-log-while-executing-a-report-062812/

Comment: I enabled logging and found something. Check edited article